# SQL Login notification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to be notified of SQL Server logins that has a particular value for the `Application Name` property of the connection string. Can someone help me to get these type of notifications by email or by any other recommended method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [logon trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx). In the trigger you can inspect the connection application name (note that this setting is not secure and can be easily spoofed). Use [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) to send yourself mail.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is not the best and most secure solution, but it is the only one I can use at the moment. Thanks.